# Can't get quest for combining dragon priest masks

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There is a quest to combine the dragon priest's masks. I have all the masks but haven't received the quest yet. I was told you get it after you get all the masks - I have been waiting for a long time, is it a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That quest is unmarked and never appears in your journal. Find the [wooden mask](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wooden_Mask) outside [Labyrinthian](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Labyrinthian) and put it on, then you'll need to put the 8 masks on a rack to receive the [9th](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Konahrik).

Comment: Where is it in outside of it or somewhere by it

Comment: @jasonvalderrama it's inside an outdoor structure. You can read more about it in the linked article on Labyrinthian.

Comment: @jasonvalderrama if this answered your question, you should mark it as accepted by pressing the green arrow on the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

If you have been past the main mission where you have to go to the Sky Haven Temple then you should be able to get the quest by going to the Blades leaders. located at Sky Haven Temple and they will tell you about the quest and the masks. They will however ask that you kill paarthurnax and will not give you the quest if you don't (you can however still get the masks, and the reward too, it just won't say you completed the dragon mask quest). If you do kill paarthurnax the grey beards will not like your actions and will no longer 'welcome you with open arms'.

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with the final Dragon priest mask. This has something to do with the Main Questline.